# creating option for select JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create two options with values `'electro'` and `'auto'` using JQuery or JS. Select has name 'butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling' and I've already wrote this part of code:

```
<script>
function addOption() {
select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling');
for(var i=0; i<select.length; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

}
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem/question? You seem to have a partial solution with no real details of what you need help with.

Comment: Hey Alex, I provided a few different method in my solution, `forEach()` and `for..of`, with the options as both an array (same value and text, parts *1* and *2* respectively) and an object (values with associated text, parts *3.1* and *3.2* respectively). Let me know if you would like a jQuery solution as well. Happy to add!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    function addOption() {
      var optionArr = ['electro', 'auto'];
      var select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0];
      for(var i=0; i<optionArr.length; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.text = optionArr[i];
        opt.value = optionArr[i];
        select.add(opt);
      }
    }

    addOption();
  });
  
</script>

<select name="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling"></select>
```

Comment: Console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: @Alex, I think you have missed the index `[0]` in `document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0]`.

Comment: I actually didn't

Comment: @Alex will there be multiple select elements with the same name in your code? If not, the `[0]` may make sense to use. If you are and would like to use the same options in all of them, then yes, we may want to loop through the select elements as well as the options array.

Comment: @Alex, the issue could be that your script is running before the DOM is fully loaded. I have fixed that by pacing the code inside `DOMContentLoaded` event. Please check the updated answer:)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a couple of different ways even using just vanilla JavaScript!

If you only have one select, you will not need to use a for loop of any select elements that match the name you specified. Rather, let's create an array of all the values you'd like to use for the options, and cycle through those to create the new options. We won't even need to use a function,n though you certainly can if you'd like to:

## 1. Using a `.forEach()` loop

Using the `.forEach()` array method, we can cycle through array items effortlessly:

```js
const options = ['electro','auto'];
const select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0];

options.forEach(option => select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`));
```

```html
<select name="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling"></select>
```

## 2. Using a `for..of` loop

You can still use a standard `for` if you'd like, or you can use the more modern `for..of` loop to avoid unnecessary indexing (e.g. `options[i]`):

```js
const options = ['electro','auto'];
const select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0];

for (option of options) {
  select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`);
}
```

```html
<select name="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling"></select>
```

## 3. Using associative keys/values

Using a JS object, we can associate the values of the new selects with a different term you might like to display in the select box to the end-user. This will work for either method, the array `.forEach()` method, or the `for..of` loop. Here are example of both:

#### 3.1. Using `.forEach()` with associative keys/values

```js
const options = { electro: 'Electric Vehicle', auto: 'Automatic Vehicle' };
const select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0];

Object.entries(options).forEach(([optionValue, optionText]) => select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<option value="${optionValue}">${optionText}</option>`));
```

```html
<select name="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling"></select>
```

#### 3.2. Using `for..of` with associative keys/values

```js
const options = { electro: 'Electric Vehicle', auto: 'Automatic Vehicle' };
const select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0];

for ([optionValue, optionText] of Object.entries(options)) {
  select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<option value="${optionValue}">${optionText}</option>`);
}
```

```html
<select name="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling"></select>
```

Comment: Hi, @Brandon McConnell, In every sollution of yours I have an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I found an error, I made echo with `"` and you it in your code too. I got thought `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of undefined`

Comment: @Alex each of these live snippets above runs without issue if you click "run" above. What might be happening is that the dollar sign from the template literals throwing an error because it is conflicting with jQuery. This would surprise me, but it may be possible. Could you post a link to your code where I can see and inspect this issue— CodePen, CodeSandbox or something like that?

Comment: @Alex that new error you're getting must mean that the select was not found. Did you make sure to include `[0]` index at the end of the selector? It should be `const select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0];` since without the `[0]` the variable will save the entire matching NodeList, not just the one element.

Comment: no, I coppied everything you wrote and put script in the bottom but error is not solved

Comment: The only thing that could be causing that issue is if the JS is looking for that element before it is present on the page. Is your JS at the bottom of your page, or the top? If it's at the top, you'll want to load the JS all wrapped in a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { … });` event. Not a bad idea to include this either way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230908/discussion-between-brandon-mcconnell-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

The entire example using Jquery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<select id="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling"></select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function addOption() {
            var options = ['electro', 'auto'];
        
            options.forEach(element => {
                $('#butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')
                .append($('<option></option>')
                        .attr('value', element)
                        .text(element));
            });
        }

        addOption();
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```